# How to insist on https in browsable api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework running at: https://dev-example.domain.com in kubernetes behind a kubernetes Ingress with http traffic disabled.

Note this is not NGINX nor Traefik. It's an Ingress controller setup on GCP.
This concept is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)

Therefore, trying to go to http://dev-example.domain.com returns a 404. Rightfully.

In the Browsable api, however, all links are prefixed with http:://
[image]

Therefore, when one of these links is clicked on, the redirect returns a 404.

Is there a setting that will allow that prefix to be https?

Answer (score 0):

This means django doesnt know your request was over HTTPS, There are several methods you can use to tell it you are using HTTPS.

For example Django will respect the X-Forwarded-Proto Header so have Nginx or whatever you have in front of Django forward that to your application.

i.e

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: I'm using Kubernetes Ingress. Where exactly would I add this definition to that yaml?

Comment: depends on the Ingress used, If you use Nginx its like what i did above, if you are using Traefik then its their http.redirect settings, if you are using nginx you might hit https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4096 this bug which is about how it doesnt forward the proto header. That link has both configurations and work around for what you are asking.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress

Comment: Do you mean you are using GCE as a Ingress? The kubernetes project maintain both GCE and Nginx as Ingress controllers and there are loads of third party Ingress controllers too, and if you are using the nginx-controller see the bug i linked you above this. Anyway i would double check that you aren't already receiving proper headers, can you print your request object headers from within django?